# How can i dynamically paint background in certain color, in my table?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to style background color of certain characters. Something like filtering(highlighting) the corresponding character name. For example, highlight the characters with no vehicles from the API,
or two shortest characters etc.

My JavaScript code:

```
const urlFetch = 'https://swapi.dev/api/people/'; /*fetch  request adress*/

let tableWrite = document.getElementById('table-content');

const fetchAPI = async () => { //Fetching data function
    try {
        const response = await fetch(urlFetch);
        const data = await response.json();
        // console.log(data.results); 

        data.results.forEach(result => {
            console.log(result); 
            // Create row and 5 cells for data
            const row = tableWrite.insertRow(-1);
            let nameCell = row.insertCell(-1);
            let eyeColorCell = row.insertCell(-1);
            let heightCell = row.insertCell(-1);
            let birthYearCell = row.insertCell(-1);
            let vehiclesCell = row.insertCell(-1);
            // Write data in the cells
            nameCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(result.name));
            eyeColorCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(result.eye_color));
            heightCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(result.height));
            birthYearCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(result.birth_year));
            vehiclesCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(result.vehicles.length));
                 
        });
    } catch {
        console.log('Oooops, something is wrong!');
    } finally {
        console.log("Fetch session completed!");
    }
}

fetchAPI();
```

Comment: If your fetch works, then please rewrite the question in a [mcve] using the `[<>]` snippet editor with a relevant example of the fetched object

Comment: What do you mean by "characters"? As in individual letters of text?

Comment: What I mean by 'characters', are characters from the fetched API- something like: "Luke Skywalker" etc...in that API I fetch let's say vehicles.length and get data od number 0.
Then i go through all table content and check what "characters" have length of 0 and then style its background to "blue" etc.